# R == (equal to operator)

Tags: r, equals

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting FALSE?

```
> 2074.49*10^3 == 2074490
[1] FALSE
```

Can you also advise me better ways to check the equality?

Comment: `> 0.3 - 0.2 == 0.2 -0.1
[1] FALSE`

Comment: "Can you also advise me better ways to check the equality?" ->  `all.equal(2074.49*10^3, 2074490)` or rather `isTRUE(all.equal(2074.49*10^3, 2074490))`. The latter prevents a verbose output if the numbers are not equal within the limits of floating-point accuracy.